# Auctex: replacing quotation marks with proper TeX ones

Tags: punctuation, emacs, editors, auctex

I'm LaTeX-ifiying a document produced by exporting an MS Word document into plain text.  I'm wondering if there's some automatic method for replacing all the double quotes, so that

```
"quoted text"
```

is replaced with

```
``quoted text''
```

I can't do a simple search and replace, as the replacement obviously has to be done in pairs: a different replace for the beginning and the end of a quote.  I'm using emacs with auctex, but if this is better handled by an external package or a shell script I can do that instead.

Comment: something like: sed -e '/"\([^"]*\)*"/``\1\'\'/'

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

Interactively, you can use

```
M-<
C-M-% ["]\([^"]*\)["] RET ``\1'' RET !
```

---

or

```
(query-replace-regexp "\"\\([^\"]*\\)\"" "``\\1''" nil (if (use-region-p) (region-beginning)) (if (use-region-p) (region-end)) nil nil)
```

Comment: The interactive one is nice but it keeps the original `"` I think...

Comment: My apologize for the mistake, I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather unorthodox solution by macros. Create a macro and then repeat it over the text. The advantage is that it is somehow interactive and you can check if there are missing pairs etc. A not so optimized version would be something like this:

```
F3 C-s " RET Ctrl-SPACE C-s " RET Ctrl-b Ctrl-w Ctrl-b Ctrl-d Ctrl-d `` Ctrl-y '' F4
```

Which reads like this:

Start the macro (`F3`) then search for " with `C-s " RET`. Start selecting (`Ctrl-SPACE`) until the next " (`C-s " RET`). Then go back one character (`Ctrl-b`) to exclude the closing " and kill the selection by `Ctrl-w`. Go back and delete both quotation marks (`Ctrl-b Ctrl-d Ctrl-d`) write LaTeX style quotations ``, yank the killed selection (`Ctrl-y`), close the LaTeX quotations and end the macro with `F4`.

If you are still following (!), by repetitively pressing `F4` emacs would go through the whole documents and replace the quotations. I copied some Jack London text and tested the macro. It looks like below. Note the pauses are me trying to see if macro has done correct job...

[image]

Comment: I think query-replace with hitting 'y' or 'n' is also sufficiently interactive... but still this is good.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, defiantly! But I've kind of a fetish for macros ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an entirely different approach, which is available to you if you can use LuaLaTeX to compile your document: Don't do anything about the `"` characters in the input file. Instead, let LuaLaTeX replace them "on the fly" with smart quotes.

The code shown below provides a Lua function, called `convert_dumb_quotes_to_smart_quotes`, which does all of the replacement work. The code also provides two LaTeX macros, called `\QuoteConvOn` and `\QuoteConvOff` respectively, which switch the operation of the Lua function on and off. Being able to switch off the Lua function is useful if your document contains verbatim-type material that contains `"` characters -- those characters should presumably not be converted to smart quotes, right? It's also useful if some of your bibliographic entries contain URL strings which feature, you guessed it, `"` characters, as those shouldn't be converted to smart quotes either.

The only input requirements are (a) that all dumb quotes are properly paired and (b) that no pairs of dumb quotes are broken up across lines. I trust that these requirements are too burdensome.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % or 'luacode' environment
%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
function convert_dumb_quotes_to_smart_quotes ( s )
   return ( s:gsub ( '"(..-)"' , "``%1''" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code:
\newcommand\QuoteConvOn{\directlua{ 
  luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
  convert_dumb_quotes_to_smart_quotes , "dumb_to_smart" )}}
\newcommand\QuoteConvOff{\directlua{ 
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
  "dumb_to_smart" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\QuoteConvOn} % switch function on by default

\begin{document}
"Hello" World. Hello "World."

\QuoteConvOff  % switch off the Lua function
\verb+"Hello" World. Hello "World."+
\end{document}
```